# Bash: iterate over json array and stringyfy the json value

Tags: arrays, json, bash

I have a json file(test.json) with following structure

```json
[
  {
     "key1" : "value-1",
     "key2" : {
       "key3" : "value3"
     }
  },
  {
     "key1" : "value-2",
     "key2" : {
       "key4" : "value4"
     }
  }
]
```

I want to covert the file content into following given structure

```js
[
  {
     "key1" : "value-1",
     "key2" : "{\"key3\":\"value3\"}"     // basically the stringyfy form of json
  },
  {
     "key1" : "value-2",
     "key2" : "{\"key4\":\"value4\"}"     // basically the stringyfy form of json
  } 
]
```

I tried like following, able to convert key2 into stringyfy JSON but not sure how to update into JSON. Whatever references I am getting from existing stackoverflow question, they are just adding new value to the existing json object. I need to read the existing value and modify the same and then update it to same json array

```bash
jq -c '.[]' $BUILD_DIR/test.json | while read i; do
    echo $(jq -r '.key2' <<< "$i") | jq '@json' 
done
```

Following one is working for me if I just need to direct update the key2 value, This might look very obvious one but I am very new to bash script syntax.

```bash
jq '( .[]).key2 |= "foo"' $BUILD_DIR/test.json
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
jq 'map(.key2 |= tojson)'
```

**Output**

```json
[
  {
    "key1": "value-1",
    "key2": "{\"key3\":\"value3\"}"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value-2",
    "key2": "{\"key4\":\"value4\"}"
  }
]
```

[Demo on jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/QihW1wGDmbl)

Comment: Are you sure you want `tostring` instead of `tojson` here? I assume that if there were a string in the input, we'd want a JSON-escaped version of that string in the output, instead of just leaving it as-is.